# Hamcrest generics hell #2 : iterableWithSize gives errror "is not applicable for the arguments"

Tags: java, generics, testing, junit, hamcrest

In hamcrest (1.3.RC2, with no JUnit dependencies) 
I am failing using `iterableWithSize().`

I have an (extension of) an `Iterator` parametrized with `Content` like this
`EndResult<Content> contents = contentRepository.findAllByPropertyValue("title", "*content*");`

where `EndResult` is 
`package org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion;`
`public interface EndResult<R> extends Iterable<R> {...}`
and `Content` is a my Pojo.

Now, I would think that this would work 
 `assertThat(contents, iterableWithSize(1));`

but it gives me the error :

**The method assertThat(T, Matcher) 
in the type Assert is not applicable 
for the arguments 
(EndResult< Content>, Matcher< Iterable< Object>>)**

I also tried these failures :

`assertThat(contents, iterableWithSize(equalTo(1));`

`assertThat(contents, IsIterableWithSize.<EndResult<Content>>.iterableWithSize(1));`

These are my imports :

```
    import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
    import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsCollectionWithSize.hasSize;
    import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsIterableWithSize.iterableWithSize;
    import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
    import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
    import org.hamcrest.collection.IsIterableWithSize;
```

The hasSize for collections works as expected, but for iterators I cant even find a working example...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should just be

```
assertThat(contents, IsIterableWithSize.<Content>iterableWithSize(1));
```

`iterableWithSize` is typed on the *component type* of your `Iterable`, not the concrete type of iterable itself.

Comment: Thanks Mark - indeed compile time its ok, but when test is run I get java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: an iterable with size <2>
     got: <org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.QueryResultBuilder$1@1970ae0>

Comment: @Agelos: Then I guess you'd better fix either your code or your test!  I was answering the Hamcrest question, you've either got a wrong assumption or some code is broken.  I'm sorry but I don't know enough about Spring to answer the new question.

Comment: But since EndResult<R> extends Iterable<R>, what else could be wrong in the trivial {next();i++} code ?

Comment: @Agelos: Are you trying to get me to help you debug code that you haven't given?  I'm not going to be of much help.  If you are still having a problem either edit your question or ideally ask a new one, since I think I've quite definitively helped you solve your original problem.

Comment: absolutely you've helped me greaty on the original question, and I thank you!
Check my new question ,and BTW, if by any chance you know any Hamcrest members in here that could help, it 'd be neat! 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727711/hamcrest-generics-iterablewithsize-gives-errror-is-not-applicable-for-the-arg