# Hamcrest: when iterableWithSize fails, it gives a bad message like "got: com.xxx.MyIterClass$1@1970ae0"

Tags: generics, iterable, hamcrest, spring-data-neo4j

In hamcrest (1.3.RC2, with no JUnit dependencies) I am failing using iterableWithSize() with a SpringDataNeo4j library.

I have an (extension of) an `Iterator` parameterized with `Content` like this

```
EndResult<Content> contents = contentRepository.findAllByPropertyValue("title", "*");
```

where `EndResult` is

package org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion; 
public interface EndResult extends Iterable {...}

and `Content` is a a `@NodeEntity` Pojo.

With the help of [Mark Peters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/228171/mark-peters) I [learned that I should call it like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707531/hamcrest-generics-hell-2-iterablewithsize-gives-errror-is-not-applicable-for)

```
assertThat(contents, IsIterableWithSize.<Content>iterableWithSize(2));
```

*since `iterableWithSize` is typed on the component type of your `Iterable`, not the concrete type of iterable itself.*

But when test is run I get

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected: 
an iterable with size <2> 
got: org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.QueryResultBuilder$1@1970ae0
```

Trying to figure out whether either 1) I am doing some thing wrong, or 2) hamcrest or 3) Spring Data Neo4j has an bug, I checked my object at hand, and it seems OK as an `Iterable` :

```
 public static int iterSize(Iterator iter){     
    int i=0;                        
    while (iter.hasNext()){ i++;iter.next();}                       
    return i; 
 }
 public static int iterSize(Iterable iter) {return iterSize(iter.iterator());}

 assertEquals("contents contain 2 items", 2, iterSize(contents)); // works OK
```

So I guess it possibly concludes that its hamcrest that has a problem. 
Has anyone tried anything similar with IsIterableWithSize ?

The test code is https://github.com/anodynos/SpringDataNeo4jTrials/blob/master/src/test/java/sdnTests/test/HamcrestIteratorSizeTest.java

Comment: I don't understand; in your hamcrest assertion you expect an `Iterable` with size 1 but in your normal JUnit assertion you expect an `Iterable` with size 2, so of course one will fail.  If you want help you need to post an example that actually demonstrates the problem (ideally reproduced without Spring if possible, as that narrows down the problem).  See http://sscce.org.

Comment: @Mark, the size of the Iterable I pass is not the issue here - obviously it fails the same way with either 1, 2 or any other int with `java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: an iterable with size <1>
     got: <org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.QueryResultBuilder$1@1d382ab>`

Comment: No, what is at issue is that you are expecting help without giving a clear example of the problem.  Give us a compilable, self-contained piece of code that demonstrates the problem.  That's your due diligence.  And you're past the generic issue, so rename and edit your post since this has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Thank you Mark - I was going to post a complete sscce, but I found the problem to be related to the description hamcrest gives when IsIterableWithSize fails, due the size test : it just gives a misleading message (the part after "got:"). When you pass the correct number of items it expects, the test passes.

Comment: @Mark, as you suggested I have added the test code https://github.com/anodynos/SpringDataNeo4jTrials/blob/master/src/test/java/sdnTests/test/HamcrestIteratorSizeTest.java

Comment: That code doesn't compile, please try again.

Comment: Oh, you're just wondering about the description?  Hamcrest always uses the `toString()` method of the "got" object for the "got" part of the description.  So whatever class `QueryBuilderResult$1` is (the first anonymous inner class of `QueryBuilderResult`) just isn't overriding `toString()`.  It's just a step neoj should take but hasn't (you should almost always override `toString` for data classes).  There's nothing Hamcrest can do about this.  The matchers are consulted for the expected portion of the description only, and it's not too difficult to reason why.

Comment: Thanks - I think its maybe cause hamcrest matcher has not implemented the describeMismatch() method yet.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing this less helpful message because you are using JUnit's version of `assertThat`.  If you use the `assertThat` provided with hamcrest it is able to better describe the mismatch.

Replace

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
```

with

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
```